# is there a way to add "breadcrumb" navigation to my master page in sharepoint on-premise 2013

Tags: 2013, development, master-page, navigation, breadcrumb

I am working on a sharepoint server 2013 on-premise. currently I have 3 site collections. And on some site collections I have 2 levels of sub-sites.

Now currently we depend on the left side navigation  (Quick launch links) for navigating between the site collections and their sub-sites. But the problem with the current navigation is that you can not know where in the hierarchy the current site or the current list is in. Now on most web applications this can be achieved using a breadcrumb navigation.. such as

> Home>> Sitecollection Name >> subsite Name>> List Name

so i am not sure if sharepoint provide this feature out of the box ? or if there are any third party solutions ? or last option is if i can achieve this inside my master page using javascript and/or other approaches ?

Thanks

Comment: You can use the OOTB Breadcrumb in the SharePoint 2013. Reference: http://academy.bindtuning.com/lets-bring-the-breadcrumb-back-to-sharepoint-2013/

Comment: @DikeshGandhi ok thanks for the link, it works for my site collections and subsites very well.. but the only issue i have is that the breadcrumb is being displayed inside a drop-down list.. so is there a way to show it as on one line instead as follow  "Home>> Sitecollection Name >> subsite Name>> List Name" ??

Answer (score 8):

The breadcrumb from SharePoint 2010 still exists in the SharePoint 2013 Masterpages but are hidden. You can enable it again by editing the Masterpage and remove some inline CSS and change the visible attribute to true.

Make a copy of the Seattle Masterpage and find this line:

```
<div class="ms-breadcrumb-dropdownBox" style="display:none;">
```

Remove the inline style so you only have the div class. Inside the div there will be two ID's named `DeltaBreadcrumbDropdown` and `PlaceHolderTitleBreadcrumb`. Find the value named `Visible="false"` and change both to true.

[Let’s bring the breadcrumb back to SharePoint 2013!](http://academy.bindtuning.com/lets-bring-the-breadcrumb-back-to-sharepoint-2013/)

The OOTB icon is not to fancy, but you can override it with some JavaScript and an icon of your own.

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot for the great reply.. now i tried your steps and worked for me where i got breadcrumb navigation working for my sites and sub-sites.. but as you mentioned on your reply the OOTB icon is not to fancy and also having the navigation links on a dropdown is not very user friendly... so can i chnage the look and feel of the dropdown to show the breabcrumb links on one single link (as in the standard breabcrumbs) something as follow  :- 
"Home>> Sitecollection Name >> subsite Name>> List Name" ??

Comment: You should be able to get back that look. Check this out blog, where it's described in detail how to do it: http://blog.sharepointexperience.com/2015/08/sharepoint-2013-breadcrumb/

Comment: now generally speaking is the breadcrumb navigation something that is provided inside publishing and non-publishing site collections??

Comment: @johnG No. However, the author states that the traditional breadcrumb and non-publishing sites does not work all the time or misbehaves.

Comment: now seems the built-in dropdown breadcrumb will work on all the sites, subsite regardless if they have the publishing features enabled or disabled... but when i try to use the following traditional breabcrumb `<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="customBreadcrumb" runat="server">
    <asp:SiteMapPath runat="server" SiteMapProvider="SPContentMapProvider" RenderCurrentNodeAsLink="false" NodeStyle-CssClass="breadcrumbNode" CurrentNodeStyle-CssClass="breadcrumbCurrentNode" RootNodeStyle-CssClass="breadcrumbRootNode" HideInteriorRootNodes="true" SkipLinkText=""/>
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>`

Comment: I faced an issue where i have a team root site with publishing features enabled,, but this team site have subsites, and these subsites do not have the publishing feature enabled,, so in this case the traditional breadcrumb worked on the root site but not on the subsites,, although from my root site i chose to use the same master page on all the sub-sites.. not sure what caused this ??

Comment: Me neither, i stuck with the dropdown navigation. :)